# Can anyone identify the airplane in this 1920s/30s photograph?

Tags: aircraft-identification

[image]Can anyone identity the aircraft in this photograph (taken late 1920s or early 1930s, I think)?  It belonged to my great-grandfather, who lived near Milwaukee, Wisconsin, however, I have no idea where the photograph itself was taken.  The plane seems similar to a Stinson SM-8.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are correct; it's a Stinson Junior. The engine in the old pic is definitely a Wright Whirlwind, based on the exhaust port orientation and the valve covers, and having 7 cylinders, means it's probably a [Whirlwind J-6-7](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wright_Whirlwind_series) 760 cubic inch radial.  That means it's likely a Junior [SM-8B](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stinson_Junior), or possibly an SM-2AC, both of which had that engine.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your help.  I couldn’t figure out why the engine seemed different from other photographs of that model, and was confused by the lack of a window behind the door (again, what I’ve seen in other photographs).